# Test to determine the CMRR in a measurement device with 4-20mA input

Tags: adc, 4-20ma, cmrr

I would like to measure the CMRR on a measuring instrument for 4-20mA current loops. The goal is to measure the CMRR of the entire system, not just the amplifier.

That is, the relationship between the normal input and a noise with respect to ground.

It is a closed instrument, of which there is only access to the input terminals and the output of the ADC through a microcontroller.

Browsing the internet I have found the following two possible methods.

Could someone tell me if either of the two is a correct method?

**Method 1:**

I use the following equation to calculate the CMRR on ADC system:

[image: CMRR on ADC equation]

This would be the setup diagram for the test:
[image: Measure CMRR on 4-20mA ADC]

The procedure would be the following:

1- With SW1 open:

a) I apply 4mA in I1, with which I obtain a voltage Vd1 and an “OutputCode@Vd1”

b. I apply 20mA in I1, with which I obtain a voltage Vd2 and an “OutputCode@Vd2”

2- I close SW1 and apply an alternating voltage of 50Hz and value Vcpp with which I obtain an “OutputCode@Vc”

3- I calculate the CMRR in the following way:

ADiff=(OutputCode@Vd2-OutputCode@Vd1)/(Vd2-Vd1)

ACM=(OutputCode@Vc-OutputCode@Vd2)/Vcpp

CMRR=ADiff/ACM

**Method 2:**

Based on the standard: [IEEE1241-2011 Standard for Terminology and Test Methods for Analog-to-Digital Converters](https://class.ece.iastate.edu/djchen/ee509/2018/IEEE1241-2011.pdf)

The CMRR is measured by applying the following formula and circuit:

[image: Test setup measuring CMRR IEEE1241-2011]

Therefore, it would be enough to apply a common mode signal at a known frequency and amplitude. Then, read digital output and convert it into volts knowing the transfer function of the system. In the end, apply the formula to obtain the CMRR

Comment: The ADC must have a two wire input, differential or otherwise in order to do an ACM test.

Comment: In this case the aim is to measure the CMRR of the entire system, not just the amplifier. That is, the relationship between the normal input and a noise with respect to ground. It is a closed instrument, of which there is only access to the input terminals and the output of the ADC through a microcontroller. Do you think that the procedure described is a correct method?